# PHP dynamically echo out query result columns without using column name

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, loops

I'm trying to output query results into a `<table>` but I'm in a dilemma.

I know I can simply do:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query)) {
       echo "<td class='cell100'>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td class='cell100'>" . $row['dynamic_col_1'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td class='cell100'>" . $row['dynamic_col_2'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td class='cell100'>" . $row['dynamic_col_3'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td class='cell100'>" . $row['dynamic_col_4'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td class='cell100'>" . $row['dynamic_col_5'] . "</td>";
}
```

The problem is depending on the user's settings - `'dynamic_col_1'` to `'dynamic_col_X'` will not necessarily appear in that order neither necessarily have that particular name.

I'd like to keep the user's defined order and dynamic column names as already sorted from the query.

How can I achieve this without using the column names - `$row['dynamic_col_X']` seeing as it changes from one user to the next? Is there a way to use array keys or something similar?

Comment: `$row['dynamic_col_' . $i]`

Comment: @u_mulder what is variable `$i`? Also the dynamic columns could be strings without numbers - like `apple`,`pear`,`peach`

Comment: you can iterate through `$row`: `foreach($row as $key => $value) {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a foreach, looping over the columns, and then tweak to suit whatever you're doing:

```
foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
    echo $column . ' ' . $value;
}
```

Comment: The rows have at least 13 colums.

Comment: That doesn't matter? This will give you the column name as `$column`

Answer (score 0):

You can [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) `$row`:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<td class="cell100">', implode('</td><td class="cell100">', $row), '</td>';
}
```

> Returns [...] a string representation of all the array elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element.